# Search a text file for unknown text in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, loops, text, replace

I have a text file which contains information that i want to find and replace, and save to a new file.
The text file is full of a load of text, but somewhere in it contains a view number as below.

```
- " Name="View 12"
- A few lines lower down it will contain:
-" Name="View 21"
```

I need to be able to search for the first view name (in the order it is in the text file, not in numerical order of views), and replace the first name with "Page 1", the second name with "Page 2", third with "Page 3" etc.

At the moment i am using a Replace function to find the char and replace with a new char.

I am able to change the "view" part to "page" but not the number.
Here is the code for this that i have at the moment. 
I don't know how to search for the view number as it could be anything. 
It could be because i have messed up the loops, or that I am not using the right functions. Anybody got any ideas or suggestions please? Thanks.

```
    Dim oldChar As String
    Dim newViewName As String

    For anInt = 1 To 40

        oldChar = ("Name=""View " & anInt)
        newViewName = ("Name=""Page " & i)

        While anInt = 1
            fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\Documents\Views.txt").Replace(oldChar, newViewName)
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Documents\New.txt", fileReader, False)
            anInt = 2
            i = 2
        End While

        fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\Documents\New.txt").Replace(oldChar, newViewName)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Documents\New.txt", fileReader, False)
        i = i + 1
    Next anInt
```

UPDATE:

The problem i was getting is with the numbering. If the order of views in the text are

```
- View 1
- View 3
- View 5
- View 7
```

Then i can happily change the "View". But the number is not changing in order. It is remaining in the same order, 1,3,5,7 in this case. I want it to read:

```
- Page 1
- Page 2
- Page 3
- Page 4
```

Comment: So you have a text file that could be full of anything, but somewhere there is `Name="View 12"` and further down `Name="View 21"`, etc. You want to replace each of these with Page X, depending what order they're in?

Comment: Correct, depending in the order they are shown in the file as you scroll down. Not in order of the view numbers

Comment: And it's always "Name", or does the name actually change?

Comment: it is always "Name=", followed by a string e.g.  Name="View 1000", or  Name="abc"  etc

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know what your textfile exactly looks like it is hard to give good advise. However, I would read the textfile into a string and then split the textfile. I would then use contains function to find Name. This piece of string I would replace with the new text and the next array elemt I would replace with the number.

Here is an example:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   Button1.Click
    Dim oldtext1 As String
    Dim newViewName As String
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim testext As String = ""
    Dim str As String()
    oldtext1 = "Name=""View "
    newViewName = ("Name=""Page ")
    testext = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\Users\gerhard\Desktop\test1.txt")
    str = testext.Split(" "c)
    For i = 0 To str.Length - 1
        If str(i).Contains("Name") Then
            counter += 1
            str(i) = "Name=""Page "
            str(i + 1) = counter.ToString
        End If
    Next
    For Each word As String In str
        Debug.Print(word)
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

The problem is you increment `i` every time you loop through `anInt`. You need it so that only increments if a replacement took place

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\Documents\New.txt").Contains("Name=""View " & anInt) Then i += 1
```

---

Like minimalist said, a little more info would be helpful

I've just looped through each line of the text file. If it contains the matching string, replace it. Either way, the line is then written to the new file.

```
    Dim sr As IO.StreamReader
    Dim filename As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "Views.txt")
    Dim newfilename As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "new.txt")
    Dim newfile As System.IO.StreamWriter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(newfilename, True)
    Dim pageNumber As Integer = 1

    If IO.File.Exists(filename) Then
        sr = IO.File.OpenText(filename)

        Do While sr.Peek <> -1
            Dim thisLine As String = sr.ReadLine
            If thisLine.Contains("Name=""View ") Then
                newfile.WriteLine(thisLine.Replace("Name", "Page " & pageNumber.ToString))
                pageNumber += 1
            Else
                newfile.WriteLine(thisLine)
            End If
        Loop
        sr.Close()
        newfile.Close()
    End If
```

This was done assuming `Name=` are going to be on different lines, as you said they would be.

If you want to be safe I would avoid `.Replace` and look at removing and inserting substrings, to avoid accidentally replacing something you shouldn't be.

Comment: I have tried this code as well as what Minimalist said. They both output the same as what i was previously getting. I will edit my question and explain...

Comment: The problem is the part of code that says  `newfile.WriteLine(thisLine.Replace("Name", "Page " & pageNumber.ToString))`. We don't want to replace the "Name" part, but the string that comes after the = sign, where Name="View 1"

Comment: Forget my old answer, yours should work if you increment `i` properly. Right now, `i` might as well be `anInt` in your code

Comment: p3tch, thanks for your reply. This almost works, however it now prints out `Page 1="View 1", Page 1="View 3", Page 1="View 5"`, instead of `Name="Page 1", Name="Page 2", Name="Page 3"`

Comment: Are you using code different to what's in your question? It should just be `.Replace(oldChar, newViewName)` which doesn't change "Name" in your code

Comment: Yes but oldChar equals View + a random integer. Not just "View ". I tried to define this random integer with anInt but it is not changing the value in the output file. Instead it will print `"Name=Page 11", "Name=Page 13"` instead of `"Name=Page 1", "Name=Page 2"`. Sorry, it is very confusing i know, but difficult to explain over this.